# Maven Builds with Different Dependency Configurations

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am working in a big product line, in which we can link dependencies (jars) on the run-time. We have multiple customers and each customer uses a different capability set, i.e a different set of jars. Since the pricing changes depending on the set of capabilities we provide, we only want to include the necessary jars on each release depending on the customer.

Let me clarify it with an example. Suppose that I have 4 jars: **A, B, C, D**. We have three customers and we only release the jars given below to each of them:

- **Customer 1:** A, B, C
- **Customer 2:** B, C, D
- **Customer 3:** B, D

Currently, we have different executables, where each of them has different Maven dependencies (customer1 executable depends on A, B, C). However, the number of customers and thus, the number of configuration sets increases so they want me to research a more modular way to take releases with different dependencies. Where can I start this research? Parametrizing the dependency sets and passing that parameter to the release command makes sense to me but I don't know how to achieve that. Do you have any advice or experience on this?

**Note:** We use Jenkins for releases if it's important.

Comment: you can make each capability as a job choice parameter, so you can decide to choose which choices according to capabilites customer need.  Then you seed the jars of choosen capabilities into pom.xml dynamically, Then execute maven building with the modified pom.xml

Comment: For each executable I would make a separate project which is under version control there you can define the different dependencies und full control. Or a multi module build which contains those projects and you can create a release of all of them in one go...the other question is: Are those project A,B,C,D etc. in different Maven projects or do you have all of them already in a single multi module build?

Comment: Each executable is a separate project in its current state but we don't want the number of projects to grow too much. They are grouped under different projects but the distributions (executables) are separated from them. That's actually why we don't want a lot of executables because we want to keep versions in each group the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is have a pom.xml per client and have the dependencies in there.

If you want to try a modular way including jenkins, the solution I see is:

- make maven profiles for instance 3 profiles ABC, BCD, BD.  to act as parameters
- make a jenkins job that would take a string parameter like ABC
- build the command mvn install -PABC

A more modular solution:

- use gradle, that means: convert your pom to a gradle buid file
- optionally configure what dependencies are included by default based on a groovy file you include using "apply" in your build file
- use gradle parameters to include the dependencies and override the default ones
- make a jenkins job that would take a string of parameter like dep1,dep2,dep3
- split this string into an array and iterate to build the command gradle -Pdep1 -Pdep2 -Pdep3

Comment: Having poms for each client is the current approach we have but having ten or more seems like a burden. Creating different profiles and Jenkins jobs could be the answer though. Unfortunately, Gradle is not an option at the moment.